# why interface cannot be final?

Tags: java, interface

**JLS 2.13.1 Interface Modifiers**

> An interface cannot be final, because the implementation of such a class could never be completed.

If I can write create static inner classes in interface I can provide implementation in it so why is such restriction

```
interface Type {

    // Normal
    class Value {
        private Value() {
        }

        public void print() {
            System.out.println("Test");
        }
    }

    public final Value value = new Value();
}
```

Comment: Please provide some code for what you propose to do.

Comment: What would be the point of a `final` interface?

Comment: @MaVRoSCy indeed valid. Just did a google. is it very commonly written that way?

Comment: @mauris never used anything like that

Answer (score 4, accepted):

BTW: nested classes were not available when this restriction was first defined, so really the question might be why this restriction was not lifted.

---

A `final` class cannot have any sub-classes.  It is considered best practice to only use interfaces for defining method(s) of sub-classes, so the two are contradictory.

You can use interfaces for other things

- annotations
- javadocs
- constants
- defining nested classes only.

but these are incidental to the purpose of an interface.

Answer (score 9):

Well in Interfaces you cannot provide any form of implementation at all: Not even static methods. It doesn't make sense to make any method final because they're yet to be implemented.

#### Code Examples:

If let say I have an interface named `IExample` and its concrete implementation `Example`:

```
interface IExample{

    public final void run();

}

class Example implements IExample{

    // wait! I can't override because it's final! but it's yet to be implemented?!
    public void run(){ 
        
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

"When the final keyword appears in a class declaration, it means that the class may never be subclassed or overridden. This prevents over-specialization of a particular class. In some sense, the person who created the class considered any further changes to be tangential to its primary purpose."

Reference: [Final](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa233803%28v=vs.60%29.aspx)

Interface represent behaviour, rather than implementation, therefore it makes no sense for it to be final.

Answer (score 0):

> If I can write create static inner classes in interface I can provide implementation in it so why is such restriction

Yes, you can declare an inner class there, but point remains that a `final` interface would be an interface that it is impossible to implement.  Any class that implemented it would be violating the `final` restriction.  The Java designers concluded that this didn't make much sense, and since there are no convincing *use-cases* for `final` interfaces with nested classes<sup>*</sup>, there is no justification for relaxing this restriction.

<sup>* - I won't claim that one could not invent a use-case.  However, I've never heard of people writing interfaces with inner classes, with the intention was that the interface *should* not be implemented.</sup>